# Upgrade to 11.04 freezes on boot

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

i saw a couple of threads about upgrade problems. but none i found that is similar to my issue.

i upgraded from 10.10. after all the upgrades/updates and went to reboot. the system would freeze when starting the services, i would turn it off and on again. the freeze is random. i.e. starting apache2 [ok]..then later..checking battery state..then later..starting nfs [ok]...

i went to recovery mode and removed some of the services. but it still wont work.

any ideas how to go fix this?

thx!

joey

Comment: Does your caps lock key flash (or the num/scroll lock keys?) when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I can manage to boot by using an older Linux version from the GRUB menu (try going back 1 version). That should let it boot, but there are obviously other problems which I don't yet know how to solve.

**Edit:** I managed to solve the problem by reinstalling Ubuntu. I do not know why it was freezing on startup, but a reinstall did fix the problem. If you do reinstall, make sure to backup all your data before doing so.